# A question on Stinespring dilation

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Stinespring dilations says if one has unital Completely Positive  map $\Phi$ from a C-star algebra $A$ to $B(H)$, then there exist a Hilbert space $K$ where $A$ can be represented, say $\pi: A \rightarrow B(K)$ a $\ast$ homomorphism, such that $\Phi(a)=V^{\ast}\pi(a)V$, where $V:H \rightarrow K$ is bounded operator. Can anyone give various examples of Stinespring dilations? I want to understand the statement using examples. In particular, what is it if applied to matrices, commutative or other situations?

Comment: Your question would likely be better received if you provided some context: what a Stinespring dilation is (or at least a reliable link to a brief reference).  You want to understand "the statement" but you haven't told us what "the statement" is!  And it would be nice to understand why this is interesting to you

Comment: Details have been provided.

Comment: @postmortes: asking for the definition of Stinespring dilation in a question than mentions C$^*$-algebras and is  tagged `operator-algebras` is ridiculous. It is a completely standard concept. This was a bad question, but not because that.

Comment: @MartinArgerami forgive me for having standards different to your own please.  I find a question that talk about completely standard concepts I've never heard of, despite working in Functional Analysis and Banch space Theory to be lacking a certain something.  I did see that you've left a detailed answer on another Stinespring dilation question though... perhaps you might have explained what's wrong with this question (in your opinion) instead of complaining?

Comment: @postmortes: the question is bad because any question of the form "I have seen this definition, please give me some examples" is bad. And in any class and/or textbook those examples would be what the student practices to understand the concept. As for standards, I'm not sure what your standards are; in the [last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4193174/22857) you answered the OP mentions $W^{1,p}(U)$, which I don't know what it is, even though I work in Functional Analysis. Why didn't you request the asker to include the definition?