# Why does it not make sense to talk about functions on sets with measure zero? Trace Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

In the context of Sobolev spaces, there is a theorem called [Trace Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_operator). In Evans (page257) he says that

> Since $\partial U$ (the boundary of $U$, I believe it is safe to assume this is open) has n-dimensional Lebesgue measure zero, there is no direct meaning we can give to the expression $u$ restricted to $\partial U$.

Here $u \in C(cl(U))$ the space of uniformly continuous functions.

Now the Trace Theorem defines a linear map $T: W^{1,p}(U) \to L^p(\partial U)$ such that

(1) $Tu = u|_{\partial U}$

(2) $T$ is a bounded linear map (and hence continuous).

Now what I don't get is

1. Isn't $L^p(\partial U)$ equipped with the norm $\int_{\partial U}$? He said the boundary has measure zero, so isn't the norm $0$?
2. Again he still writes $u$ restricted to the boundary for $T$, is this just notation? I just don't get what this means.
3. He also talks about zero traces after the theorem. Is this just a theorem about when PDEs have homogenous boundary conditions?

Comment: Sobolev and Lebesgue spaces don't have "functions" exactly; they have equivalence classes of functions from which a representative is chosen, and then we pretend that these are "functions" in the usual sense.  So when you look at a Sobolev space function on a set of measure zero you need to have a way of selecting your representative because they can all disagree with each other on the measure zero sets; they only agree off that set.

Comment: @postmortes let me rewrite my answer. So basically if $f = g$ a.e. on a set of measure zero, say $X$, then the set $\{ f \neq g \}$ has measure zero. So in every case, this class of functions is defined on a set of measure zero. And does this imply this class is just the zero function? And that's why it has no meaning?

Comment: Let $f \in W^{1,p}$ for the sake of argument.  This is a Sobolev space, so $f$ is a representative of an equivalence class of functions.  There are *many* other functions $g$ that are equal to $f$ everywhere *except* on a set of measure zero, say the boundary $\partial U$.  So, when we're on $U$ we can use $f$ and treat it as a function, as every other function in its equivalence class has the same values on $U$ so they are "the same" for our purposes.  But on that set of measure zero you now need to specify *which* $f, g,$ or whatever you're using as they are not "the same"  there

Comment: @postmortes I am revisiting this particular comment after a month to think about it. I understand why you chose $\partial U$ in that particular example, if the set where $\{ f \neq g \} = \partial U$ then we have a problem. But what if you didn't choose the boundary?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  Generally you don't get to choose the boundary of $U$, you are given $U$ and whatever its boundary is as part of the problem you're studying.  You can choose problems where you make the boundary intractable if you like, in which case you will probably need to prove a new trace theorem of your own, or find alternative techniques to handle the boundary

Comment: I might be reading this wrong, but since we started with a function $u$ on $U$ that is defined a.e., we never established a rule for defining $u$ on the boundary. And I think that is the problem. The boundary being of measure zero shouldn't have anything to do with this right? 

In the comment you replied, I was just referring to your original example of "say the boundary $\partial U$". It almost sounded like you chose it to illustrate an example for me.

Comment: Ah no, that's just rhetoric.  The boundary of $U$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure on it has measure zero in the situation you're looking at, which is why you end up needing a trace theorem.  it is possible to have intractable boundaries (see Cacciopoli sets, I think) but don't worry about them at this stage :)

Comment: I didn't understand a word of what that means here. I mean the boundary being measure zero has nothing to do with the problem we are talking at right? It's a matter of how to assign agreeable functions to the boundary. In this case, it is restricted to talking about measure zero sets (the boundary). When we say $\{ f \neq g \}$, the set which they do not agree on, it is only *some* set $N$, so if $N$ isn't the boundary, why are we focusing on this part? This last question shouldn't even exist right? Who cares if the boundary has measure zero, that isn't even the main problem right?

Comment: Two functions in a Lebesgue class differ only on sets of measure zero (didn't we already cover this?).  So if your boundary isn't of measure zero, the function is well-defined there.  Thus the boundary having measure zero w.r.t Lebesgue measure on the set is the whole point of the need for the trace theorem.

Comment: Anyway, I'm at work and can't carry this on right now.

Comment: Are we using the same definition? In my definition, two functions $f,g : U \to \mathbb{R}$ are defined equal a.e. if there exists $N \subset U$ such that $\mu(N) = 0$ with $N  = \{ f \neq g \}$, it is not just any sets of measure zero. We started the functions on $U$, not $\overline{U}$, so we don't have a rule of establishing functions agreeing on the boundary. And it is not necessarily that $\partial U \subset U$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that Evans identifies is that when we have a function $u$ defined on an open set $U$ and belonging to the Sobolev space $W^{1,p}(U)$ and we want to extend that to the boundary we run into problems.  As he notes, if $u\in C(\bar U)$ additionally then we are fine: $u$ is well defined on $\partial U$ in this case and we can proceed.  But if not, then because $u$ is only defined a.e. in $U$ (i.e. is a representative of an equivalence class of functions that agree everywhere except, perhaps, on sets of measure zero) then we don't have an obvious strategy for determining what $u$ looks like on $\partial U$.

Note that $\partial U$ is only a set of measure zero here in terms of $W^{1,p}(U)$ because the boundary has codimension $1$ with respect to the Sobolev norm.  That means that we can consider $\partial U$ as a Sobolev space in its own right, with its own norm, and then we can look for a way to extend $u$ (as uniquely as possible) to $\partial U$.  The conditions under which we can do that are given by the *Trace theorem* as you've identified.

So, we look for a continuous linear operator $T: W^{1,p}(U) \rightarrow L^p(\partial U)$.  Each space is equipped with its own norm, so answering your question $1$, no, the norm is not identically zero on $L^p(\partial U)$.  For the sake of clarity, let's say that $Tu = v$.  Our specific requirement is that $u=v$ on $\partial U$.  Should $v$ somehow have values on $U$ outside of $\partial U$ we don't care.  We will never look at that.  So we can write $Tu = v = u_{\mid \partial U}$ in order to emphasize where our $v$ actually lives and why we're talking about it.  So your second question is answered as: yes, this is notational convenience to help you understand what's going on and where this value on the boundary has come from.

You haven't, for whatever reason, transcribed the statement of the theorem correctly though: condition (i) is:

$$ Tu = u_{\mid \partial U} \mbox { if } u \in W^{1,p}\cap C(\bar{U}) $$

-- we are forcing the boundary values to be taken from those functions that do exist on the boundary.  Since these functions are chosen from $W^{1,p}$ they are still part of the equivalence class, so they still equal $u$ a.e. on $U$.  So this is a sensible choice, and allows us to state what we're doing here:

*we define $u$ on the boundary by looking at the subset of functions that are continuous of the closure of $U$ and accepting the values they have in common on the boundary as the boundary values for any $u \in U$*

We call $Tu$ the trace of $u$ on $U$ because it's a kind of remnant or left-over -- it's not what every $u \in U$ would give, but it's the best we'll get as several such $u$ agree there.  So the values are like a tracery over the boundary.  (That might be rather too poetic for many people, feel free to ignore it.)

Finally for your third question: typically when a function takes infinitely many zero values we start suspecting that it's actually zero everywhere, and if $Tu=0$ that's what we might suspect.  But we're dealing with a subset of all $u \in U$ now, and equivalence classes to boot, so we need to check our intuition.  Theorem $2$ then looks at what it means to have $Tu=0$ on $\partial U$ and concludes that $u$ does not have to be identically zero, but only that needs to be compactly supported on $U$ (i.e. it can vanish everywhere outside of $\bar U$).  That is what Evans means by $u \in W^{1,p}_0(U)$.

Compactly supported is awesome -- compactness is one of those "we can't have finite but this is almost as good" properties that we should grab whenever we can get it.  If all we have to do to prove $u\in W^{1,p}_0(U)$ is show $Tu=0$ on $\partial U$ that's a pretty good offer.

Comment: 1. When you say codimension of the boundary is 1, what is that in an infinite dimensional space here? Can you be more specific?

Comment: 2. About $L^p(\partial U)$, you say it is now Sobolev, but where are the weak derivatives? Or maybe we are saying we embedding the weak derivatives inside Lp? I am not still not seeing why the norm isn't $0$. I am stuck on the idea that we are still integrating over a set of measure zero.

Comment: You should look up codimension -- it's pretty standard in what you're studying and it will help you to know it.  The codimension of $Y$ in $X$ is $\dim (X\setminus Y)$.  In finite dimensional spaces we can just say that the boundary has one dimension less than the principal space, but (as you rightly note) that doesn't make sense in infinite dimensions

Comment: The $L^p$ spaces are the trivial Sobolev spaces if you like, they're the ones with no weak derivatives bounded additionally.  We start with $L^p$ and place restrictions on them to get the Sobolev spaces, so they're base spaces for the concept. As for measure zero: try thinking of projecting your functions $u$ onto the boundary.  They won't necessarily vanish (in fact, they can be quite porous in some sense and still project to an interval) and their norm in $L^p(\partial U)$ won't vanish either because they're a "large" set relative to the boundary topology

Comment: The reason for my cxdimension comment is you mentioned how the boundary has codim 1 with respect to the Sobolev norm, so with respect to the Sobolev space. But the Sobolev space is infinite dim, so that what I don't get what you mean. With respect to dim(X/Y), what are we quotienting out? The boundary?

Comment: You either need to ask a new question about codimension or look it up -- I don't think I can give you a good explanation in 600 characters (which is what the comments allow).  $X$ and $Y$ are (at minimum) normed linear spaces, so yes, here we can identify that $\dim (U\setminus \partial U)=1$.  Having an infinite dimension doesn't mean we can't talk about that dimension relative to other spaces that it contains, and is quite necessary for some parts of Banach Space theory.

Comment: Hang on, you quotient the boundary from $U$. I thought you were trying to quotient boundary from the Sobolev space W(U). So are you talking about the space $W(\partial U)$ when you were talking bout "with respect to the Sobolev norm"?

Comment: Sorry yes.  And I am sorry, I tend to forget that $U$ isn't the Sobolev space itself but the underlying set when I'm talking about these things.

Comment: May i ask what is "boundary topology" meant here?

Comment: And isn't the boundary always $n-1$ dimensional anyways? So it has codimension 1, what does that even have to do with "with respect to the Sobolev norm"?

Comment: The topology on the boundary.  Any space can be given a topology, though there are often "obvious" choices for it.  In this case, just as an example, if you consider a plane in $\mathbb R ^2$ then the topology on that can be given by consider circles with the Euclidean norm $\|\cdot \|_2$.  However, on any line passing through (or bounding some part of) the plane the open sets are naturally open intervals.

Comment: You can take a look at Giusti's book of Functions of Bounded Variation and Cacciopoli sets (it's hard) if you'd like to see more about what happens when you thicken a boundary of something, but for where you seem to be at the moment you can assume that boundaries will always have codimension $1$ :)

Comment: I should've been more specific with my question on the boundary topology thing. I just meant that since we are in $R^n$ right now, the boundary here is just some subspace right? So it inherits topology from the R^n space. But what does that have to do with making sure the norm isn't $0$ after projection? I don't think i quite understand that last sentence ("large set"). I have to head for bed soon, unfortunately (its 4am...lol), but I would love to hear your answer.

Comment: I have to get to work -- I've been in the office for 20 minutes now without getting properly started on anything.  Yes, the boundary here is just a subspace, but the open sets in each subspace are different.  An interval has measure zero in $\mathbb R ^2$ but full measure in $\mathbb R ^1$ when viewed using natural Lebesgue measure on each space -- that's why when you use $T$ to "drop down" a dimension you don't have norm $0$ -- you've changed space, you've changed norm, and the measure used to define it.  And it's why you need $T$ -- you can't just change measure on the ambient space.

Comment: Okay so I reread your post again and you are right, I missed the fact that $u$ has a continuous extension to the boundary because it is uniformly continuous, hence we are really looking at the domain $\overline{U}$, not $U.$ But you have been telling that it is the weak derivative condition that doesn't extend to the boundary and talking about values restricted there doesn't make sense since $\partial U \subset \overline{U}$ and $\mu \{ f \neq g \} = 0$, and unfortunately $\partial U$ is one of those sets, so it doesn't make sense to talk about it.

Comment: But this Trace Theorem is only providing an artificial answer, since this $Tu$ thing is just pretending to be values on the boundary since if it were a true "restricted to boundary", it would be defining $u \in W(\overline{U})$. At least that's my take