# a function defined only upto a set of measure zero

Tags: measure-theory, sobolev-spaces

What does it mean that a function in Sobolev spaces (for example) to be defined **only upto a set of measure zero**?

Comment: This is how we define $L^p$ space. If $g = f$ almost everywhere we consider it the same elements in $L^p$.

Comment: perhaps of interest to you, many comments and discussion: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4193174

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing particular about Sobolev spaces here. If $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a measure space and $Y$ is any set, we can define an equivalence relation on the set $\mathcal{F}(X,Y)$ of all functions from $X$ to $Y$ by saying that $f\sim g$ if $$\mu\big(\{x\in X \mid f(x)\neq g(x)\} \big) = 0.$$Check that this is an equivalence relation. The very common abuse of notation is to denote the equivalence class $[f]$ of $f$ by $f$ itself. Saying that $f$ is defined up to a set of measure zero means, effectively, specifying the equivalence class but not actually choosing a representative for such class.

Comment: thanks, i think i understand it now